# Проблема с заданием отладчика gdb в QtCreator

Tags: qtcreator, gdb

Возникли проблемы с заданием отладчика gdb в QtCreator 4.5.0
При попытке начать отладку(F5) выходит сообщение:

> "Не удалось создать отладчик. Пожалуйста, включите в разделе «Настройки отладчика» на странице «Запуск» режима проекта."

Отладчик gdb расположен в соответствии с прописанными путями[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но по какой-то причине его тип не определяется и он не валиден.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при попытке вызвать gdb руками через cmd, вышла ошибка которая для меня является большой загадкой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом gdb связан с python?
И как устранить проблему связанную с отладчиком?

Предполагаю, что проблема связана с переменными окружения, но что конкретно не могу понять. Пытался удалить из PATH всё что связано с python 3.6(Anaconda), но ничего не помогло.

Использую следующие инструменты для сборки приложения:

- Компилятор mingw
- cmake для генерации makefile
- ОC WIN10 x64

Comment: gdb использует питон для "prytty print" - красивого форматированного вывода. Может оно все таки нашло другой питон на Вашей машине и подцепило его? Кстати, машину перезапускали (ну или хотя бы сеанс)?

Comment: Да, пробовал. Копаю в настоящее время в сторону переменных окружения. python упоминается в двух переменных PYTHONPATH и PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался. Спасибо [KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim), подкинул мысль на счёт python.

Действительно в состав qdb входит python 2.7, а так как у меня стоит 3.6 то он подхватывал его. Помогло то, что в переменную PATH загнал пути к библиотекам python и интерпретатору.

- C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\opt\bin;
- C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\opt\lib;

Кривой конечно вариант, но рабочий